# Moving a site, links/admin do not work

Tags: 7, backups

I moved a drupal installation from one server to another.
Steps I followed:

1. Copied whole directory structure from old server.
2. Exported database from old server.
3. added files to newdomain/drupal
4. Imported database
5. edited settings.php with new database information.

As of right now the home page is working (Except for some broken non-db images, but I know the reason for that and can fix it) But none of the links to any of the nodes or any of the admin paths I know seem to exist. I get a 404 File Not Found error.

I wonder if it's related to the fact that this installation is in a subdirectory and the other one was not, but is that enough to make every page except the homepage not function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link to the modules and themes are hard coded in the system table in the database. Reset them by visiting 'admin/modules', clear the cache, make sure clean urls are on, and make sure any op code cache like APC is cleared if you are using that.

Comment: I can't access admin on the new location, but would it work to do that on the old site and then re-export the database?

Comment: Have you tried mysite.com/?q=admin/modules or mysite.com/[new directory]/?q=admin/modules

Comment: Ah that second url format allowed me to get to the login page, and then to where I need to go

Comment: I don't see anywhere to clear the cache, though.. I have the devel module installed, but don't see any option there, either.

Comment: You can clear the cache at 'admin/config/development/performance' but first you will need to turn off clean urls at 'admin/config/search/clean-urls'

Comment: just turning off clean urls seemed to do the trick

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's possible. You can try to adjust the used base URL by setting the $base_url value in your settings.php .

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem! The cause was a missing .htaccess file...it didn't get copied when I copied all the other site files. Once I copied that file into the test site, I was able to re-enable clean urls.

Answer (score 0):

For windows server users: 
 I had same issue. I added .htaccess file but no success. On windows server you need to

- open IIS
- click URL Rewrite
- Import Rules
- point to your .htaccess file in Site
- import -> Remove any error shown
- Apply Rules.

That should solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any **languages** configured, you might have to go into the database directly and reconfigure the URLs under the table:  `languages`, then change the settings under `domain`.

You can also configure these settings in the GUI under: `/admin/config/regional/language` if you can get to it.

**DON'T FORGET to clear your caches afterward.**