# All links point to the old site after migration

Tags: 7, migrations, configuration

I migrated a Drupal 7 site from 1 server to another. Let's call the old site URL http://oldsite.com and the new site url http://newsite.com. I have copied over the code base and the database. The site displays correctly on http://newsite.com, however all the links point to http://oldsite.com. The only way to access the links are to type the URL in the browser (e.g. http://newsite.com/admin).

I have read lot of forums and done the following:

1. Set the $base_url in settings.php
2. Cleared cache in Config > Development > Performance
3. Cleared the cache table in DB
4. Ran update.php
5. Disabled clean urls

Nothing has worked. Someone suggested changing an entry in system table. Don't know which entry they were talking about.

Can anyone suggest the correct steps and perhaps an explanation of why I keep getting the redirects?
I have also referred to [Moving a site, links/admin do not work](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22044/moving-a-site-links-admin-do-not-work).

Comment: Did you try this module https://drupal.org/project/pathologic

Answer (score 1):

For sites being localized, you have to edit every language:
`/admin/config/regional/language`
It's because there's a "domain" field that is left with the wrong URL in the database. 
That solved my case of moving from *subdomain* **beta**.mysite.com to **www**.mysite.com

Answer (score -1):

If you are using domain access, be sure to check the table PREFIX_languages. I had the exact same problem and wasted 2 days before I found the problem. The old domain was hard coded in the PREFIX_languages table and once I changed it everything worked perfectly.

Comment: There is no indication that the OP is using Domain.